# How can I use one Nav Bar code on multiple pages, BUT have the current page highlighted?

Tags: javascript, php, html, nav

So, I run my church's website and I try to stay pretty basic in the coding, but we have seasonal pages that we add and remove from the website all the time so I get tired of changing the "simple" HTML code on every page for the nav bar. I have found where I can use PHP and have one code, like  but is it possible to have the current page highlighted, i.e. on our website now, the current page name is bold and a different color.

I have also seen JS do this ([Highlighting current page in the nav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206942/highlighting-current-page-in-the-nav)) but I don't really understand how to implement this, so if you think this could be the better route for me, and can help explain how to do it, that would be cool.

Any help would be great!

Comment: This can be solved using only CSS, but it would be helpful if you provided some HTML.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. On my work website, I use PHP to add additional CSS classes to HTML nav elements on my website that styles it up to show the user they are on a particular page.

Comment: with PHP you could either look at the current page's name or for a variable you'd specify only on the specific pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an `id` attribute to the `body` tag of each of your pages, like this:

```
<body id="home"> <!-- this would be for your home page for example -->
```

...

```
<body id="about"> <!-- this would be for your about page... -->
```

add the same to the `li` tags of your nav, like this:

```
<li id="home">Home</li>
<li id="about">About</li>
```

then in the CSS file just do this:

```
body#home li#home, body#about li#about { // style of the active menu item }
```

Comment: For the most part, this is working, THANKS! I'm having issues with the CSS on the highlight though, I have the php include inside a div with id navbar. This will make a difference on the CSS, but I've tried a combination of things and can't make it work.
'<div id="navbar">

            <?php include("nav.php"); ?>
</div>'

Comment: '<ul>
                <li id="home"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                <li id="about"><a href="about_us.html">about</a></li>
                <li id="calendar"><a href="calendar.html">calendar</a></li>
                <li id="sermons"><a href="sermons.html">sermons</a></li>
                <li id="gallery"><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
            </ul>'

Comment: body#index li#index,
 { color: #c0392b; font-weight: bold;}