# Current Menu Page Item Background Not Changing - CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am trying to get a little graphic to designate which page the viewer is on with css, but it just won't highlight. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
 <ul class="side-nav">
 <a href="http://www.cieloazulsantafe.com/nav-test.html"><li><span>Home</span></li></a>
 <a href="http://www.cieloazulsantafe.com/sample-page.html"><li>
 <span>Sample Page</span></li></a>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
 ul.side-nav span{
  margin-left: 50px;    
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  }
 ul.side-nav a li{
 background: url('http://cieloazulsantafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/nav-grad.png');
 list-style: none;
 height: 41px;
 width: 250px;
 line-height: 2.0;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
 ul.side-nav a li:hover{
 background: url('http://cieloazulsantafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/nav-grad1.png');   
 }
 ul.side-nav a li.current-menu-item{
 background: url('http://cieloazulsantafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/nav-grad1.png');
}
a{
text-decoration: none;  
}
```

Seems straightforward, but I just can't get the background to change. I know its because its the li element, but I guess the "current-menu-item" order is wrong.

Url : http://cieloazulsantafe.com/nav-test.html
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, your HTML is broken. don't put `<li>` between `<a>` tags. `<ul><li><a href="#">foo</a></li></ul>` is OK, `<ul><a href="#"><li>foo</li></a></ul>` is not OK. Even if `:hover` works and everything is displayed, browser works in quirks mode

Comment: something (a javascript call or a php check) will have to make the menu item get the `current-menu-item` class, otherwise it won't work

Comment: I need the entire `<li>` to be an active link.

Comment: @webeno he can also use unpopular anchor's `:active` selector but first of all he need to fix his html

Comment: `<ul class="side-nav"><li><a href="#"></a></li></ul>` Ok

Comment: hm, @Peter, I was giving it another thought (looked it up) but the :active pseudo class doesn't actually work by styling the menu item, it merely acts when clicking the menu item... (source: [http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/)). Am I missing something?

Comment: @webeno no you are absolutely right, I haven't used it in a while so I mixed up things

Comment: @toolbox3 You may want to select one of the answers as the correct one, assuming it did resolved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @webeno that I didn't get back to you guys. I appreciate all the help. That day I was looking at all the answers and it really wasn't getting me anywhere. So I kept working on it and got engrossed and forgot about this question. My bad. I ended up using sprites and figured out the current-menu-item myself. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @toolbox3 well, sprites don't have much to do with list items getting their active/current class, so purely from the point of view of this specific question, you could still select one answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to name the body (give it an id) and the `li` tags, and refer to them respectively in your css. This is the easiest, pure css way.

**HTML**

```
<body id="home-body"> // ... on your home page
```

...

```
<body id="about-body"> // ... on your about page
```

**Your nav**

```
<li id="home-menu">Home</li>
<li id="about-menu">About</li>
```

**CSS**

```
body#home-body li#home-menu, body#about-body li#about-menu { // style of the active menu item }
```

You might want to have a look at my answer I provided on the following question: [How can I use one Nav Bar code on multiple pages, BUT have the current page highlighted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490994/how-can-i-use-one-nav-bar-code-on-multiple-pages-but-have-the-current-page-high)

**EDIT:** This is the "pure css" way; but depending on your needs, there might be other ways down this road.

Comment: You should never have two id's with the same name. It's bad practice.

Comment: sorry @webeno I dont see advantage/difference in write so much code to add a style, instead of just add the `current-class` on the `<li>` you are writing for each page an different ID on the body, in my opinion its unnecessary css code. Change something on your response so that I can take it the downvote, I put there for the duplicate ID but you change it.

Comment: @Mattos This IS the pure CSS method, man, your method is always going to highlight only the one menu item you added the `current` class to, it will never change to the actual menu item once another one is clicked, whereas if you apply my solution, it will. I suggest you do a bit more research before downvoting a correct answer!

Comment: @Mattos Here's another URL to support my theory : [http://www.mstudiostalk.com/2008/03/11/pure-css-to-display-the-active-page-in-the-navigation/](http://www.mstudiostalk.com/2008/03/11/pure-css-to-display-the-active-page-in-the-navigation/), also I am using this actively on a couple of my own websites with success.

Comment: @webeno Ok, I get your point, I see the benefit more clearly now, sorry, I need you to edit your answer, anything really, otherwise the system dont let me change the down vote.

Comment: @Mattos Done, appreciate your cooperation!

Answer (score 0):

### CHECK THIS FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/aN2ny/

Your HTML and CSS were broken:

### HTML

```
<ul class="side-nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Current</a></li>
</ul>
```

`<a>` has to be inside the `<li>`, put the text properties on the `<a>`. Most important you forgot to put the class `current-menu-item` on the current `<li>`.

### CSS

```
ul.side-nav {
    margin-left: 50px;    
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:0px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 250px;
 }
 ul.side-nav li{
     padding:0px;
     margin:0px;
     display:block;
     background: url('http://cieloazulsantafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/nav-grad.png');
     height: 41px;
     cursor:pointer;  
 }
ul.side-nav li a {
    margin:0px;
    display:block;
    padding-left:50px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff;
    height:41px;
    line-height:41px;
}
ul.side-nav li a:hover, 
ul.side-nav li.current-menu-item {
     background: url('http://cieloazulsantafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/nav-grad1.png');   
 }
```

There are several minor changes, take a look at the code.

Comment: this will always highlight that one menu item, but I understand the OP wants the menu item to be highlighted in case the viewer is on the respective page.

Comment: @webeno of course, he can put manually the class or via js on each page. There is no way to do that with pure css.

Comment: That's not correct, have a look at my code. It has also been accepted as the correct answer on the referred question.

Comment: I could downvote your answer, but I don't think it would be fair, as, while I don't think you fully answer the OP's question, it is partially a correct answer, and I've seen it being given to many similar questions. I'd still appreciate if you could remove your downvote from mine, especially if you haven't tested and apparently incorrectly assume it's a wrong answer.